# another proof for the countability of integers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Suppose you have a function $n-4$ so you have $N_4 = \{\mathbb{N} \cup [-4, -3, -2, -1, 0]\}$. Obviously the countable union of countable sets is countable, so $N_4 $ is too. Take $n$ to range over the set it is in, and you have a countable set.

Can we also say that anything that is discrete is countable? The real numbers need not be discrete.

Comment: The countable union of countable sets is not necessarily countable, unless one has the axiom of countable choice.

Comment: If $n$ is fixed, as your first sentence indicates, then $n-4$ is not a function, just a number. What is $N_4$ supposed to be? The range of some function? What you wrote seems to be a singleton set (whose only element is also a set). I suspect this is not what you meant. Anyway, it is not clear how $N_4$ is relevant to the problem. And why $N_4$ is the union of $\mathbb N$ and a set of size *five*.

Comment: Perhaps instead of $n-4$ what you had in mind was the function $f_n:\mathbb N\to\mathbb Z$ given by $f_n(m)=m-n$ (so your $N_4$ is the range of $f_4$ or $f_5$, depending on whether you use the convention that $0\in\mathbb N$ or not). If this is the case, then your idea is correct, that the range of each $f_n$ is countable, and letting $n$ vary over $\mathbb N$ results in a countable collection of countable ranges whose union is $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: (And to address @MichaelAlbanese's objection, note that choice is irrelevant here since you have an explicit enumeration of the range of each $f_n$, so Cantor's argument explicitly results in an enumeration of $\mathbb Z$. No use of choice is needed.)

Comment: (There are also problems with the last paragraph in the question, but the issues are now of a different nature: What precisely do you mean by "discrete"? If you mean as a subset of $\mathbb R$, then yes, any discrete set is countable, but the argument is more involved than showing that $\mathbb Z$ is discrete. If you have a more general setting in mind --for example, discrete spaces can be defined purely topologically, without reference to the reals-- then no, there are uncountable discrete spaces.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: My objection is valid. The statement "Obviously the countable union of countable sets is countable" is neither obvious nor true. In this context, you don't need choice. I commented in this way just as I would if a user had made the statement "Obviously every even number is a multiple of $4$, so $8$ is a multiple of $4$".

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese No need to argue with me, I am well aware of the issues here. I was indicating to the OP how to modify what they wrote, and how to address your objection in the context of that modification.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: I wasn't trying to argue, I was just pointing out (more to the OP, than you) that I was justified in making that comment. I suppose your initial comment was not really directed towards me. Sorry if you felt I was attacking you.

Comment: (@MichaelAlbanese Don't worry about it, I didn't feel "attacked" or anything of the sort.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $A$ is countable (or denumerable) if it is equipotent to $\Bbb N$, meaning there is a one to one correspondence from $A$ to $\Bbb N$. Thus, to prove $\Bbb Z$ is countable you should set up a bijection between it and $\Bbb N$. For example, say I map the negative integers as follows $-n\mapsto 2n$. Where would you map the positive integers to finish up?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

> Using the definition: a set $A$ is countable if there's a bijection $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb N$.

Prove that the map
$$f:\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb N,\quad n\mapsto\left\{\begin{array}{cl}\\
2n& \text{if} \ n\geq 0\\
-2n-1& \text{if} \ n< 0\end{array}\right.$$
is a bijection.

Comment: +1 Personally, I'm getting tired of $0$'s! I've certainly noticed a decline in upvotes/upvoting over my time here at MSE!

Answer (score 0):

There are discretely ordered sets of arbitrarily high cardinality. Just take any ordered set $A$, and the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Form the direct product $A\times \mathbb{Z}$. For any two ordered pairs $(\alpha,m)$ and $(\beta,n)$, define $(\alpha,m)\lt (\beta,n)$ if $\alpha\lt \beta$ or $\alpha=\beta$ and $m\lt n$.  The reulting order is discrete, but $A$ can be chosen arbitrarily large.